# Why does text view not take up the whole table row's width?

Tags: android, layout, tablelayout, tablerow

I am not sure if this question has been answered or not(I tried looking but couldn't find anything)
This is the portion of the layout that I have a question about.

[image]

For the selected textview, here is the xml code 
[image]

My question is why is that textview not taking up the complete width of the row. I am assuming that because I used "match_parent" for the layout_width that the textview should take up the complete width of its parent, which is the TableRow. I tried looking this situation up on the TableLayout API (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) but the only instance  in which "match_parent" was mentioned was in the situation where you add an element to the table layout without it being in a row, its width will be set to "match_parent". Does this have anything to do with rows/columns and that behavior somehow overwriting "match_parent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assign

```
 android:layout_weight="1"
```

to textview

it will occupy entire width

Comment: Thanks that worked. But do you know why match_parent doesn't? I know that layout_weight just allocates extra space